# Google Assistant: Sorry, I couldn't find that

Tags: app-actions

I will follow the steps below to configure my project：
[Github Issue](https://github.com/android/app-actions-samples/issues/7)

1、add shortcuts.xml , and use meta-data reference on Activity（android.intent.action.MAIN and android.intent.category.LAUNCHER）

```
<meta-data
                android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
```

2、config shortcuts.xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <capability android:name="actions.intent.GET_THING">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="com.etekcity.vesyncplatform.wellness.ui.WellnessDeviceEnableActivity"
            android:targetPackage="com.etekcity.vesyncplatform">
            <parameter
                android:name="thing.name"
                android:key="query" />
        </intent>
    </capability>
</shortcuts>
```

3、build generate aab upload to Google Play. I refer [app-actions/get-started](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/get-started)。

4、in the end, use Google Assistant test on AS. tips: Sorry, I couldn't find that.

5、Of course，I say "Hey Google, Find Recipe on ExampleApp" tips: to install tip.but My application was Internal testing version.

##### I don't know which step was wrong, I really need your help. Thank you!